# A new entity was found through the relationship. Doctrine

Tags: orm, zend-framework, doctrine, entity

### **The application has thrown an exception!**

Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException

A new entity was found through the relationship 'Core\Model\Filter#category' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Core\Model\Category@00000000314fc99200005639c0395a5e. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Core\Model\Category#__toString()' to get a clue.

This function cause an exception.
Some comits in code.
It is ZendFramework 2.

```
protected function handleCategory( $data, \Core\Model\Project $project )
{
    $filter = $this->sl()->get( "Core\Filter\JSON\Category" );
    $filter->setData( $data );
    if( !$filter->isValid() ){
        $id = @$data[ 'id' ];
        $report = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'messages' => $filter->getMessages()
        );
        return $report;
    }

    $filteredData = $filter->getValues(); 
    $repo = $this->em()->getRepository( "Core\Model\Category" );
    $category = $repo->findOneBy(
        array(
            'id' => $filteredData[ 'id' ],
            'project' => $project->getId()
        )
    );

    $b = false;
    if( !$category ){
        $b = true;
        $category = new \Core\Model\Category;
        $category->setProject( $project )
                ->setCreatedAt( new \DateTime() );
    }
    $category->setUpdatedAt( new \DateTime() );

    /* Hydrate Category  */
    $hydrator = $this->sl()->get( "Core\Hydrator\JSON\Category" );
    $hydrator->hydrate( $filteredData, $category );

    /* Persist Category */
    $this->em()->persist($category);

    if($b)
    {
        /* Return Filter Data */
        $filterData = $hydrator->get();

        /* Hydrate Filter */
        $filterHydrator = $this->sl()->get( 'Core\Hydrator\JSON\Filter' );
        //$filtersObj = array();
        foreach($filterData as $i => $fdata)
        {
            $filterObj = new \Core\Model\Filter;
            $filterObj->setProject($project)->setCategory($category);
            $filterHydrator->hydrate($fdata, $filterObj);
            $this->em()->persist($filterObj);

            /*Breaks after any flush after second persist*/
            $this->em()->flush();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I tried to solve this problem by:

- MERGE, but get another exception, A managed dirty+entity [...]
- cascade={"persist"}, but nothing happend.
- rewrite code in that what you see, i made all persists in one function one by one with one EntityManager.(If i missing something please tell me)

Never work before with ZendFramework. I love Symfony with app/console manager, all entities with tables creates authomatically.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem with adding

```
$this->em()->clear('Filter');
```

after

```
$this->em()->persist($filterObj);
```

And we can remove

```
$this->em()->flush();
```

To do script faster. I paste it in the end.

I think this is not good idea, but it works.
I still waiting for your answers.